# Change tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. I Wanna change tab using javascript, but it's not working with Ajax.

script:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mtabs li").click(function() {
            $("#mtabs li").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tab").hide();
            var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
            return false;
        });
        $("#simulate").click(function(){
            $('a[rel="tab1"]').trigger("click");
        });
    });
```

it works in tabs when I am using it like this:

```
<a id='simulate' href='#' onclick= edit(1);> Edit </a>
```

But don't work with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:nameList,
    type:'POST',
    data:{title:sort},
    success: function(response){
        data = response.data;
        $('.tr').remove();
        for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
            $("#table").append(
                "<tr class='tr'> <td>"+"<b>"+ title +"</b>" + response.data[i].title + "<br>" +
                response.data[i].description+
                " </td> <td> "+
                response.data[i].printYear.replace('.0','')+
                " </td> <td> "+
                response.data[i].readAlready.replace('.0','')+
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                " </td> <td> <a id='simulate' href='#' onclick= edit("+i+");> Edit </a>  </td> </td> <td> <a href='#' onclick='delete_("+
                response.data[i].id+");'> Delete </a>  </td> </tr>");
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: Mayhaps it has to do with you injecting the elements into the DOM dynamically. Instead of calling `edit()` inline try to use deferred event binding, where you bind the click event to the closest static element which seems to be `#table` specifying the actual target within the event bindings ► `$('#table').on('click', '#simulate', function(YourParam){... your edit code in here...})`

Comment: When you say `But don't work with Ajax:` do you mean the code wont work when you dynamically add content? If yes do as suggested by @Fran

Comment: uh, are you adding multiple elements with the same id (simulate)?  that won’t work.

Comment: @BoCyrill You are right. If I understood Fran correctly I need to use this with something else, not Edit link. But I need to use it with Edit.

Comment: @James Could I resolve it somehow?

Comment: @АлександрШаповалов While you can change the selector to be `[id=xxx]` it is not good to have multiple elements with the same identifier. Instead of using `id=xxx` use `data-id='xxx'` and change the selector to use `[data=id=xxx]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a class on the `<a>` instead of a duplicated id.

```
<a class="simulate"...>
```

And change your event handler to

```
$("#table").on("click", ".simulate", function(){
        $('a[rel="tab1"]').trigger("click");
  });
```